# Page number of glossary

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries

I want to reference the glossary from within the text (I'm using the `glossaries` package). However, since the glossaries are produced using `\printglossaries`, I can't just put a `\label` command where it needs to be. Putting a `\label` command just before or just after the `\printglossaries` command doesn't work: It gives the wrong page number.

I browsed through the `glossaries` manual, but didn't find anything about labels or references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch `glossaries`'  internal `\@glossarysection` macro.

EDIT: In case you were wondering what `\@@glossaryseclabel` is doing: If you load the `glossaries` package with the `numberedsection=autolabel` option, glossaries will a) be numbered b) feature an automatic label that uses the glossary type. In this case you could refer to the different glossaries with, e.g., `\ref{main}` or `\pageref{acronym}`. See section 2.2. of the `glossaries` manual for details. For *unnumbered* glossaries, use my hack below. (Naturally, `\ref`won't work correctly because there's no sectioning number to refer to, but `\pageref` will.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@glossarysection}{%
  \@@glossaryseclabel%
}{%
  \@@glossaryseclabel%
  \label{\glsautoprefix\@glo@type}% "main" for main glossary, "acronym" for list of acronyms
}{}{}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,%
    description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\begin{document}

Some text about \gls{electrolyte}.

The glossary starts on page~\pageref{main}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I had to add the `numberedsection=autolabel` option to `\usepackage{glossaries}`.

Comment: @danielkullmann Please try again -- the whole point of my hack is to make at least `\pageref` work for *unnumbered* glossaries.

Comment: The new version works for me as well, but again only with `numberedsection=autolabel`. And my glossary is still unnumbered, maybe because I also have the option `nonumberlist`?

Comment: @danielkullmann I tried again, but even with both options, my glossary is numbered. For now I suggest: If it works for you ... ;-)

Comment: I'm using memoir documentclass, so maybe that is the reason it works for me.

Comment: @danielkullmann Not only maybe. Please disclose your document class from now on or, even better, provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: lockstep: I tried your code exactly, and it works for me, but when I add \usepackage{hyperref} before \usepackage{glossaries}, it doesn't work anymore (the output is "the glossary starts on page ??"). Do you have any idea why your solution doesn't work with the hyperref package?