# Page number of glossary while using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, glossaries

I want to reference the glossary in the text. The [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40121/13051) given to this question on this website works for me.  But adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` before `\usepackage{glossaries}` makes it not work anymore (the output is "The glossary starts on page ??").  How can I reference the page the glossary is on while also using the `hyperref` package?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@glossarysection}{%
  \@@glossaryseclabel%
}{%
  \@@glossaryseclabel%
  \label{\glsautoprefix\@glo@type}% "main" for main glossary, "acronym" for list of acronyms
}{}{}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,%
    description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\begin{document}

Some text about \gls{electrolyte}.

The glossary starts on page~\pageref{main}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: With the `hyperref` package you can use `\autopageref{main}` instead of `page~\pageref{main}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’d suggest the following simple solution based on redefining `\glossarypreamble`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,
  description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{%
  \label{\currentglossary}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text about \gls{electrolyte}.

The glossary starts on \autopageref{main}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could load the `glossaries` package with

```
\usepackage[numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}
```

In this case, the glossary sections are numbered, though.

Comment: Thanks mhp. This way the reference displays as "page XX". Is there a way to omit the word "page" and just display the page number?

Comment: @mmm: Simply use `\pageref` instead of `\autopageref`.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed I'm referencing the first glossary this way. I added two additional glossaries using `\newglossary` in my document - can those be referenced separately?

Comment: @mmm: The label is added to each defined glossary. So, `\pageref{acronym}` etc.  should work, too.

Answer (score 6):

You have to create a mark for referencing and this can be done by `\phantomsection`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
%-------------------------------------------------------
\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,%
    description={solution able to conduct electric current}}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
Some text about \gls{electrolyte}.
The glossary starts on page~\pageref{glossaries}.
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection <------------------- here
\label{glossaries}<-----------------and here
\printglossaries
%-------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

The Glossary page looks like this:

[image]

Comment: For me, the actual glossary start at page 5 in your example.

Comment: @lockstep, I do not understand. I get it at page 3. Pl. see the picture.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I'm pretty new to this.  Your solution works, but I think I'm going to mark one of the others as "the answer" just because they allow you to reference the main glossary and the acronyms separately, so it seems a bit better.  Unless I can select more than one green check mark?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For a solution that works with `hyperref` and (as my original one) does without modifications in the document body, you have to patch `\@p@glossarysection` instead of `\@glossarysection`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@p@glossarysection}{%
  \@@glossaryseclabel%
}{%
  \@@glossaryseclabel%
  \label{\glsautoprefix\@glo@type}% "main" for main glossary, "acronym" for list of acronyms
}{}{}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,%
    description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\begin{document}

Some text about \gls{electrolyte}.

The glossary starts on page~\pageref{main}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much for the help.  I'm going to mark mhp's answer as my "selected answer", just because it does the same thing but seems a little simpler.  Unless I can select more than one answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @debbie It's up to you which answer to accept, but you can (and should) upvote all "helpful" answers -- note that upvoting is different from accepting.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip.  I'm pretty new to all this.