# How to print glossary entry page as a superscript note

Tags: glossaries

Well, I think it's all in the title. But for the sake of perfect clarity, I would like to renew both `\gls` and `\glspl` command so I can print a back ref to the defintion page in the output. Is there any sort of `\glspage{entry}` kinda command?

(Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40120/page-number-of-glossary/40121#40121) is a duplicate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As from version 4.16 you can use the hook `\glspostlinkhook` that's used by commands like `\gls`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[entrycounter]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\glsentrycounterlabel}{}%

\renewcommand*{\glspostlinkhook}{\textsuperscript{\pageref{glsentry-\glslabel}}}

\newglossaryentry{term}{name=term,description={an example}}

\begin{document}
\gls{term}.

\newpage

\glspl{term}.

\newpage

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This requires an extra LaTeX run to ensure the cross-references are up-to-date:

```
pdflatex filename
makeglossaries filename
pdflatex filename
pdflatex filename
```

Comment: That's a recent and very pleased update (from last week), so I had to update my `texlive`, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the entry like this

```
\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
name={Name\label{foo}}, text={Name},
description={bla bla bla}}
```

or

```
\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
name={Name},
description={bla bla bla\label{foo}}}
```

then you can use `\pageref{foo}`

Comment: Is there no hooks in glossary that could automate this? Because in that scenario, I have to edit every entry of my glossary and add a label. Plus I'll have to add 4 labels if if wanted to automate, at least, the output by renewing the `gls`, `glpl`, `Gls`, `Glspl` command.