# How to label the index and glossary

Tags: glossaries, indexing, labels

Say you want to `\pageref` to an index and/or glossary, how can you label the index/glossary?

The following approaches fail (for evident reasons):

```
\label{glos}
\printglossary

\label{idx}
\printindex
```

(labeled before the index and glossary)

```
\printglossary
\label{glos}

\printindex
\label{idx}
```

(labeled at last page of the index and glossary)

How can one label the index and glossary?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx,glossaries}
\makeindex
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
In this example we introduce \index{text}\newglossaryentry{text}{name={text},description={foo}}text. You can consult the glossary on page \pageref{glos} and the index on page \pageref{idx}.

\label{glos}
\printglossary
\label{idx}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicates: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40120/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49754/

Comment: Can you turn the snippets into a MWE (after looking at the links provided by Marijn)?

Comment: For `glossaries` you can use `\usepackage[numbersection=nameref]{glossaries}`, described in [2.2 Sectioning, Headings and TOC Options](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sectioningheadingsandtocoptions). This will automatically add a label after the glossary heading.

Comment: Assuming they are put at the end of the article, you can use \clearpage\refstepcounter{section}\label{idx} before the \printindex (same as \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{index}).

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Since it's the `\pageref` a pure label is sufficient -- you're right if it would be a numbered section

Comment: @christian Hupfer - Early experiments with \afterpage showed I needed a \refstepcounter on this page.  Any counter would do.

Answer (score 6):

For `glossaries` the simplest method is to auto-generate the label with the `numberedsection` package option¹:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[numberedsection=nameref]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{text}{name={text},description={foo}}

\begin{document}
In this example we introduce \gls{text}.
You can consult the glossary on page \pageref{main}.

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

This automatically inserts a label at the start of the glossary, where the label is given by `\glsautoprefix` followed by the glossary label. The prefix command `\glsautoprefix` is empty by default, so the `main` glossary by default has the label set with `\label{main}` and so can be referenced with `\pageref{main}`. You can redefine `\glsautoprefix` to provide a prefix to prevent any label clash.

The other possibility is to modify the glossary preamble. With just one glossary you can simply redefine `\glossarypreamble`, like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\label{glos}}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{text}{name={text},description={foo}}

\begin{document}
In this example we introduce \gls{text}.
You can consult the glossary on page \pageref{glos}.

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

For multiple glossaries, you'll either need to redefine `\glossarypreamble` before each glossary or you can use `\setglossarypreamble[main]{\label{glos}}` etc instead.

---

¹ I've moved the glossary definition to the preamble as per the [recommendation in the glossaries manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution, using `etoolbox` package.

**Note:** Please see Nicola Talbot's comment below (and the answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{makeidx,glossaries}
\makeindex
\makeglossaries

\csappto{theglossary}{\label{mtglos}}
\csappto{theindex}{\label{mtidx}}

\begin{document}
In this example  we introduce \index{text}
\newglossaryentry{bla}{name={text},description={foo}}text. \gls{bla} You can consult the glossary on page \pageref{mtglos} and the index on page \pageref{mtidx}.


\printglossary
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For `glossaries` this won't work if the glossary style is later changed (for example, `\printglossary[style=list]`) as the styles redefine `theglossary`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot of course, I did not understand your comment (answer now) first time. Thank you.